# О синтаксическом разборе предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Есть такое предложение:
"На вселение к родителям ИХ несовершеннолетних детей не требуется согласие остальных членов семьи и согласие наймодателя".
Какой смысл с точки зрения синтаксического разбора носит местоимение "ИХ".
Трактуется двояко:
 1. Либо это вселение к обеим кровным родителям отцу и матери.
 2. Либо это вселение к одному из родителей (отцу или матери).
 Прошу толкование отправить в "личку" 94912010@mfil.ru.
С уважением Владимир.

Answer (score 2):

Чьих?-ИХ - значит, касается обоих родителей, включая каждого поодиночке. Это не с точки зрения синтаксиса, это с точки зрения здравого смысла и логики. Ребёнок может прописаться и к матери, и к отцу, и к обоим родителям.

Comment: Их родителей - означает одновременное наличие кровных отца и матери (семьи). В противном случае на жилую площадь, на которой проживают разведенные родители, мать сможет вселить детей, рожденных ею от других отцов не членов семьи. Вот такой казус. Думайте - Людмила. С уважением, Владимир Федорович.

Comment: А она и может. Несовершеннолетние дети по закону всегда живут с родителями. Если развелись,а дети живут с матерью, она имеет право их прописать без чьего-либо согласия.